# Getting error: cannot read property 'map' of undefined using Fetch in React?

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to map through the JSON data using fetch in React but am getting an error with my map statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Carbon extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h5>Co2 Emissions</h5>
                <h5>Co2 Per Capita</h5>
                {this.state.data.map(data => data.data)}
            </div>
        )
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/co2-data/master/owid-co2-data.json')
            .then( resp => resp.json())
            .then((data)=> {
                this.setState({
                    data: data.url
                })
                console.log(data)
            })
    }
}

export default Carbon
```

Comment: It means `this.state.data` is `undefined` when you are trying to `map()`. Most likely, the `data` returned by your `fetch()` in `componentDidMount()` does not have a property `url`. You can try logging it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
{this?.state?.data?.map(data => data?.data)}
```

your  data.url in response may not an array  i guess that's why its throwing error, you can try this , it should work and not throw error